# Определение угла

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр, тригонометрия

Занялся разработкой 3D движка на python и возникла проблема: есть угол обзора игрока, а точнее два угла (`left = angle - FOV/2` и `right = angle + FOV/2`)
и угол относительно некой материальной точки (вершина объекта) (формула `angle = math.acos((x-self.x)/distance)`), где `x` - координата вершины объекта, `self.x` - координата игрока, `distance` - расстояние от игрока до вершины, также при `y-self.y < 0: angle = 2*math.pi - angle`)

Нужно написать функцию, которая проверяет эти три угла и выводит 0, 1 или 2: если 1, что вершина находится между left и right, если 0 то левее, если 2, то правее.

Comment: Что в данном случае означает "левее" и "правее"?

Comment: левее - значит вершина объекта находится левее left и right на окружности

Comment: Если идти от left влево, всё левее и левее, то в конце концов придёшь в right. Ну да ладно, я сделал "слева от прямой игрок-объект, учитывая её направление"

Answer (score 1):

Если работать в углах - считаем знаковый угол между центральным направлением angle и направлением на объект

```
dx = x-self.x
dx = y-self.y
diff = math.atan2(dx*sin(angle)-dy*cos(angle), dy*sin(angle)+dx*cos(angle))
if abs(diff < Fov/2):
    внутри сектора
elif diff > 0:
    слева
else:
    справа
```